# Glassfy integration with capacitor

Tags: payment, capacitor-plugin, sku

After creating SKUS on Glassfy as you can see here :
[image: Sku creation]
I tried to fetch it with this code :

```
  try {
    await Glassfy.initialize({
      apiKey:"***********************",
      watcherMode:false,
      packageName:"***********",
    });

    const offerings = await Glassfy.skuWithId({identifier:"memo_scheduled_configs_9.99"});
    console.log("offerings: ",offerings);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("offerings error: ",error);
  }
```

I got this error

ofeatures-js.js:101 Error checking SKU visibility: Error: GlassfyError(code=NotFoundOnGlassfy, description=Product not found on Glassfy. Did you add to the dashboard?, debug=null)
at returnResult (index.html:917:32)
at win.androidBridge.onmessage (index.html:892:21)

I expected to see the details of the Sku.
By the way, when I create offering and I fetch them I can get the details of the offerings successfully but for some reason the array of the Skus is always empty so I try now to access to skus directly By Id but I'm getting the Product not found on Glassfy.
please help me to solve this problem and let me know if I'm doing anything in a wrong way.